# $\frac{7 - |2x+1|}{2\cos(x)-7} < 0 $. Solve the inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the inequality $\frac{7 - |2x+1|}{2\cos(x)-7} < 0 $.
I have no clue how to solve this inequality. Please give a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all real x,
\begin{gather*}
2\cos x-7< 0\\
\Longrightarrow \frac{1}{2\cos x-7} < 0
\end{gather*}
Therefore, for the inequality to be true,
\begin{gather*}
7-\mid 2x+1\mid  >0\\
\Longrightarrow \mid 2x+1\mid < 7\\
\Longrightarrow -7< 2x+1< 7\\
\Longrightarrow -4< x< 3
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 0):

First thing, it's not an equation.

Second thing, (Hint): Note that $2\cos x-7 <0 $ for all $x\in \mathbb R$